# LocalizedError.errorDescription gets lost for wrapped errors

Tags: swift, error-handling

While optimizing error handling in my Swift application, I encountered the following odd behavior. My custom error types implement `LocalizedError` so I can provide `errorDescription` to the user. Since I cannot rely on third-party libraries to do the same, I have an `ErrorWrapper` enum with only one `case underlying(_: Error)`:

```
import Foundation

enum CustomError: Error {
    case test(_: String)
}

extension CustomError: LocalizedError {
    var errorDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case let .test(err):
            return "An error occured: \(err)"
        }
    }
}

enum ErrorWrapper: Error {
    case underlying(_: Error)
}

extension ErrorWrapper: LocalizedError {
    var errorDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case let .underlying(error) where error is LocalizedError:
            // I verified execution jumps into this block, 
            // but error.errorDescription is nil
            return (error as! LocalizedError).errorDescription ?? "Unknown error"
        case let .underlying(error):
            return error.localizedDescription
        }
    }
}

let err = CustomError.test("Foo")
let wrapped = ErrorWrapper.underlying(err)

print(err.errorDescription)     // prints: "An error occured: Foo\n"
print(wrapped.errorDescription) // prints: "Unknown error\n"
```

Is there a way to solve this problem? I thought about implementing my custom Error protocol, but would like to stick with Swift's builtin error protocols, if possible.

Comment: The `errorDescription` requirement of `LocalizedError` needs to be a property of type `String?`, not `String` :)

Comment: Also note you shouldn't have to type-cast to `LocalizedError` in `ErrorWrapper`'s implementation of `errorDescription`; `switch self { case let .underlying(error): return error.localizedDescription }` should be sufficient.

Comment: In addition to what @Hamish said, you should also print `err.localizedDescription`, so that the customized error message is returned even for `let err: Error = CustomError.test("Foo")`, i.e. you have a generic error variable.

Comment: Thank you, @Hamish, @Martin R. I still miss an `@Override` annotation in Swift :(

Comment: @Jeremy No worries! Actually in the latest 4.1 snapshot, the compiler warns that your implementations are near-misses. Although once the compiler supports variance w/ implementations of protocol requirements (https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-522), your code should work as intended anyway.